# Why won't my family move to a new house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I am trying to move my husband and two daughters to my manor in Falkreath, Lakeview manor.
I tell my husband I want to move, select the manor and he says "If that's what you want I'll meet you there soon." Then he just sits there doing nothing. Usually he gets up and goes outside. There is also no option to move when I talk to my kids, what do I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can't always tell if your spouse is moving to a house or not. Try travelling to the house you want you and your spouse to move in and he or she'll be there. If this still happens, try to wait a few days or reload and saves very often.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, it resolved itself over a span of a few ingame days. I simply didn't go to the manor for a few days. I stayed out questing or slept in inns, and when I returned they were at the manor.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a chest and bed for the kids in the new house?  You have to ask both the wife and the kids to move, and must have a bed and chest for the children in the new house before the option to talk to them will appear.